# how to write htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, iis

Asking for your help:

I want to write a htaccess rewrite rule that will redirect all urls :

```
accounts.mysubdomain.com/TB/.... --> 
accounts.mysubdomain.com/....
```

can you please help me out?

TIA

Comment: I'm sorry, you want to redirect everything that is after `accounts.mysubdomain.com/`, like `accounts.mysubdomain.com/this/is/an/example/`to just `accounts.mysubdomain.com/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in /TB/ directory to redirect to any directory (you can have absolute or relative paths instead of my_dir)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^TB/(.*)$ /new_dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you are redirecting everything in the accounts.mysubdomain.com/TB/ to accounts.mysubdomain.com then use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^TB/(.*)$ http://accounts.mysubdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```